# Most efficient coding style for forms with multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, forms, html

I am have a form that look something like this:

[image: layout]

I want the input.variable I am going to throw into localStorage based on the number of boxes filled out and the radio boxes checked. It would apply as follows:
-Radio Buttons-
One Name Typed in:
na :  Name 
F: Name and friend
F+ Name and friends

Two Names typed in:
na:  Name and Name
F:   Name, Name and friend
F+:  Name, Name and friends

Three Names typed in:
na: Name, Name and Name
F:  Name, Name Name and friend
F+: Name, Name, Name and friends

Four Names typed in:
na: Name, Name, Name and Name
F:  Name, Name, Name, Name and friend
F+: Name, Name, Name, Name and friends

What would be the best way to approach this? I am trying to think of the most efficient way to write this beyond multiple if/then/else statements.

Thanks

Comment: The best approach is thinking of a couple of ways to do what you want, and try them... what have you tried?

Comment: I am working on a mess of if/then statements that is turning into a nested nightmare. I was hoping there was a bit cleaner way to arrange the data.

Comment: if you want a clean way to arrange data, use an object literal. If you're dealing with a wash of `if elseif elseif` statements, consider using a `switch`, if all conditionals check a different value, just use `switch (true)`

Comment: +1 to you Elias.I just read up on switch, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since my comment seems to have pointed you in the right direction, I'm pasting it here as an answer:

if you want a clean way to arrange data, use an object literal. If you're dealing with a wash of `if elseif elseif` statements, consider using a `switch`, if all conditionals check a different value, just use `switch (true)`