# Switch / Case Variable Error

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I am trying to get the input of four text boxes, and display it based on the radio checkbox options. I discussed it more here:

[Most efficient coding style for forms with multiple radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662166/most-efficient-coding-style-for-forms-with-multiple-radio-buttons)

I am having trouble with the following lines of code:

```
//Gets value from input boxes  into array
var values = $('.names').map(function() { 
  if(this.value != '') return this.value; 
}).get();

//Check radio boxes
var selectedValue = $('input[name=friend]:checked').val();

//Determines array length
var length = values.length;

//if only one name
if (length==1) {
  switch(selectedValue) {
    case "na":
      values = values;
      break;
    case "van":
      values = values.join("och van");
      break;
    case "vanner":
      values = values.join("och vanner");
      break;
  }
}
alert(selectedValue);
```

It will not add the values "och van" nor "och vanner" to the variable "values". Run independently everything works. I.e. "values" return the name, "selectedValue" returns the radio box checked, and "length" returns the # of elements in the array. But when I try to combine it via an If statement, and switch case it doesn't  work.

Html in question is here:

```
    <div id="inputboxes">
      <input type="text" name="name1" id="names1" class="names" value="" placeholder="1) Name Here . . .">
      <input type="text" name="name2" id="names2" class="names" value="" placeholder="2) Name Here . . .">
      <input type="text" name="name3" id="names3" class="names" value="" placeholder="3) Name Here . . .">
      <input type="text" name="name4" id="names4" class="names" value="" placeholder="4) Name Here . . .">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div id="radios1">
      <input type="radio" id="na" value="na" name="friend" class="{src:'img/n.people.png',checked:'img/n.people.c.png',hover:'/img/unchecked.png'}"  checked="checked"/> 
      <input type="radio" id="van" value="van" name="friend" class="{src:'img/o.person.png',checked:'img/o.person.c.png',hover:'/img/unchecked.png'}"  /> 
      <input type="radio" id="vanner" value="vanner" name="friend" class="{src:'img/m.people.png',checked:'img/m.people.c.png',hover:'/img/unchecked.png'}"  /> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Post the html that corresponds to that javascript..

Comment: for future reference: don't use tabs when you post code on stackoverflow.  If you cut-and-paste, then convert your tabs to spaces before you post.  (I already edited your post to change tabs to spaces, and clean up the layout a bit, so no need to change anything on this one).

Comment: when you say add "och van"  to the values variable, what do you mean? add another element to that array with "och van" value or do you mean append that string to the existent values on the array, sorry I don't get you.

Comment: I actually figured it out. Instead of using values.join I just swapped that it with the +. Works fine, I will post updated code. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that join doesn't have any elements to join (array has only one element) and so it doesn't place your separator string into the array.  You need to have two more more elements for join to actually insert something between them.  I do notice this isn't spelled out anywhere but I suppose it should be somewhat obvious from the name.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Defined variables in the beginning, and replaced it with:

```
var och = " och ";
var van = " och vän"
var vanner =" och vänner";
var nameout;
```

and the updated IF statement:

```
if (length==1)
switch(selectedValue)
 {
   case "na":
   nameout = values;
   break;
   case "van":
   nameout = values + van;
   break;
   case "vanner":
   nameout = values + vanner;
   break;

 }
}
```